# Trigger function not working in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have tables as follows:

test

| address | value |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | 50 |

table1

| address | amount | id | hash |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 50 | 2 | se2 |

I am trying to add the amount to a1 when a new insertion of a1 is added to the test table i.e. if a new row is added to test i.e. address = a1 and value = 100 then, i want to update the amount in a1 on table1 table i.e. amount = 50 + 100 = 150 but the value does not get updated.

Here is my trigger implementation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION address_trigger()
    RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE table1
    SET amount = amount + new.value
    WHERE NEW.address = table1.address;
    RETURN NEW;
end;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER update_table1
    AFTER INSERT
    ON "test"
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE address_trigger();
```

I added the trigger function via query console and the trigger function shows on the database as update_table1 in intellij. then, i insert a new row to test manually `INSERT INTO test(address, value) VALUES ('a1',100);`. the row gets updated on test but the value is not updated on table1 on reloading. Could someone help me out, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you are not seeing a [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue where there is another `table1` that is being updated. Try schema qualifying `table1`.

Answer (score 1):

It works ok for me. Create tables

```
create table "test"(
  address varchar(10),
  value int
);
create table table1 (
  address varchar(10),
  amount int
);

insert into table1 
   values('abc', 0);
```

Your trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION address_trigger()
    RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE table1
    SET amount = amount + new.value
    WHERE NEW.address = table1.address;
    RETURN NEW;
end;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER update_table1
    AFTER INSERT
    ON "test"
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE address_trigger();
```

Test it

```
insert into "test"
  values ('abc', 10),
         ('abc', 30);

select * 
from table1;
```

Output

```
address amount
abc 40
```